# Core Data object fault - NSManagedObject attributes returns nil

Tags: ios, core-data

Recently I had a problem with such scenario:

1. In My `NSManagedObject` I stored longName attribute, called save on `NSManagedObjectContext` and after a while I close the application. Save ended without an error.
2. I restarted the application, I fetched the object and I tried to get `[object longName]`. The value which was returned was nil. When I stopped there with breakpoint and when I tried to display the value by `po [object longName]` proper value was returned and printed. ALl next calles to `[object longName]` in sources where correct. Whenever I don't use breakpoints there the value was always `nil`.

I think I hit the same problem recently in other application. I fetched the user object which contains NSSet of flights objects. When I tried to use `[[flight validFrom] intValue]` it returns number 0, but when I tried to print it with `@"%@"` format I've got `(null)`.
The strange thing is that problem occurred not on every object.